# Change TextView background with ripples

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have a RecyclerView (grid layout) whose elements are TextViews. When a user clicks on a TextView I change the color of the background. I allow for multiple selections. All of this works fine. Now I have a new requirement to show ripple when a user clicks on a TextView. So basically I must accomplish two things:

1. show ripple
2. change the background of the TextView

How do I accomplish this? I tried using `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true”` in the RecyclerView (xml) but that made no difference.

So imagine I have to change the background of the TextView between blue and green. But on top I have to always show the ripple for the `onLongClick`

Comment: Maybe I have to add the ripple through the decorator of the GridLayoutManager? how?

Comment: maybe this could be the answer: why do some buttons ripple on longClick while some don't? For example CheckBox ripples on both click and longClick. Whereas a normal button does not ripple on longClick but ripples on short clicks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Android Support library change the `android:background` of your item layout to `?attr/selectableItemBackground` or `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` which will apply the ripple on Lollipop+ devices and fallback to a full item select on lower devices.

Comment: My item is the TextView as stated

Comment: So change the `android:background` property of the `TextView` to `?attr/selectableItemBackground` or `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` and you'll get the ripple as stated :-D

Comment: Thanks for helping, but you probably misread the question. The textView has a onLongClickListener. When the long click happens I have to toggle the background of the textView between green and blue. Do you see? `textView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));` is one of the options. So the xml assignment would be lost immediately once the adapter starts binding.

Comment: @NouvelTravay So take it a step further. Wrap the `TextView` in a `FrameLayout`. Set the background of the `TextView` to the `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and call `frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));` on the `FrameLayout` since `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` are transparent...

Comment: Thanks. I get it. +1. Except one problem: ripples naturally work with click not with longClick. Do you (or anyone watching) know how to make the ripple work with longClick?

Comment: You could try adding an empty click listener if you implement the solution and it doesn't work with only longClick attached

Comment: I didn't get that. Do you mind showing an example or edit for a bit more explanation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103351/discussion-between-cory-charlton-and-nouvel-travay).