# Ripple effect on TextView long click

Tags: android, android-layout, ripple, onlongclicklistener

How do I get a TextView to ripple on long click? It ripples fine `onClick` but I need the ripple for `onLongClick`.

Comment: In case someone wants more context, my question is a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373987/change-textview-background-with-ripples

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Android Ripple Background](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background)

```
    final RippleBackground rippleBackground=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.content);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.centerImage);
    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It does not work. Your solution seems to require that the TextView be smaller than the `RippleBackground`. But that won't work for me. I need something that works similar to `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to implement a  [longClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions) this is one. Basicly an event is fired examples mouseover, onclick, onlongclick, onlistitemclick and listeners that "hear" the event. post the code if you need more help, did you have new OnLongClickListener() object created?

Comment: how this answers OP question about ripple?

Comment: if you READ he can do ripple :" It ripples fine onClick"